# installing tensorflow in windows anaconda - and running using it using Spyder GUI

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I visited [the tensorflow page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#common_installation_problems) and followed instructions from `Installing with Anaconda` section. When I tried to validate my installation, I got below errors

```
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\nik>python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tf' is not defined
>>> exit
Use exit() or Ctrl-Z plus Return to exit
>>> exit()
```

then i tried

```
(C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3) C:\Users\nik>activate tensorflow

(tensorflow) C:\Users\nik>pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting tensorflow==1.2.1 from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
  Using cached https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting bleach==1.5.0 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
  Using cached bleach-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting html5lib==0.9999999 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
Collecting backports.weakref==1.0rc1 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
  Using cached backports.weakref-1.0rc1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.10 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
  Using cached Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
Collecting protobuf>=3.2.0 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
Collecting numpy>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
  Using cached numpy-1.13.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
Collecting six>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting wheel>=0.26 (from tensorflow==1.2.1)
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.2.1)
  Using cached setuptools-36.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, html5lib, bleach, backports.weakref, werkzeug, markdown, setuptools, protobuf, numpy, wheel, tensorflow
Successfully installed backports.weakref-1.0rc1 bleach-1.5.0 html5lib-0.9999999 markdown-2.6.8 numpy-1.13.1 protobuf-3.3.0 setuptools-36.2.0 six-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.2.1 werkzeug-0.12.2 wheel-0.29.0

(tensorflow) C:\Users\nik>python
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
2017-07-20 12:20:26.177654: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-20 12:20:26.178276: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-20 12:20:26.178687: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-20 12:20:26.179189: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-20 12:20:26.179713: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-20 12:20:26.180250: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-20 12:20:26.180687: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-07-20 12:20:26.181092: W c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows\py\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

My question as below - my main question is question 3:

1. Am I suppose to validate installation after typing command -
   `activate tensorflow` as shown in the second command block above?
2. why am i getting multiple instructions after
   the command `sess = tf.Session()` ?
3. **Can i use tensorflow within the
   SPYDER gui? how? I tried below but in the SPYDER gui, but didnt get any success :(**

   activate tensorflow

File "", line 1

```
    activate tensorflow
                      ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax


import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "<ipython-input-2-41389fad42b5>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: `activate` is not a python command. It's a shell script. To use the `tensorflow` use the `python` in the `tensorflow` environment.

Comment: i am still not clear. Please explain again how i could use tensorflow within spyder gui

Comment: You have several `anaconda` environments, 2 of which are named `root` and `tensorflow`. If you know where you installed your anaconda, the environments will be in `envs/` subdirectory and the `python` you need is in `envs/tensorflow/bin/python`. `conda env list` will list all your environments.

Comment: it is still not clear. I went to `.conda` folder and I have one file that is called `enviroments` It has `C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow`. Do i need to add something here?

Comment: With that information, the python you need is `C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\bin\python`.

Comment: do i need to alter that line with the line that you have given?

Comment: In order to use `tensorflow` in your python scripts without sourcing activate you will need to run `C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\bin\python yourscript.py` instead of just `python yourscript.py`. In fact just run `C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\bin\python` and in it try to `import tensorflow` and you will understand where I am going with this.

Comment: Here's how everything works. When you run `activate tensorflow` it modifies `%PATH%` and prepends the directory `C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\bin`. The `%PATH%` environment variable affect which `python` runs when you type `python`. You can avoid `activate tensorflow` just by running the `C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow\bin\python` directly.

Comment: i went to python and typed in command `cd C:\\Users\\nikhi\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tensorflow` and then i typed `import tensorflow as tf` and i got the same error as above

Comment: if i type command `cd C:\\Users\\nikhi\\AppData\\Local\\conda\\conda\\envs\\tensorflow\\bin` then i get error `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: `

Comment: in case of above two comments, I went to SPYDER gui and then ran above commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**: Yes you need to activate the virtual environment to import tensorflow as you have installed tensorflow in virtual environment.

**Q2**: Not sure why there are multiple instructions but this is normal and is built in in tensorflow. You can avoid these by building tensorflow yourself with SIMD instructions enabled. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghv5fbC287o

**Q3**: You need to change the first step when you create virtual environment. Create virtual environment using the following command {conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 anaconda}.

The detailed answer to your Q3 is as follows:

1. Create tensorflow environment using "conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 anaconda"
2. Once virtual environment is created enter the command "activate tensorflow"
3. Now install tensorflow using "pip install tensorflow" (CPU-only) or pip install tensorflow-gpu (for GPU).
4. Now go to the folder where anaconda is installed.
5. If C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 is Anaconda root folder then go to "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\test\Scripts" and open spyder.exe. You should be able to import tensorflow successfully in this environment.

Comment: i have already installed tensorflow using link mentioned in my question. I typed command `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 ` and then `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`. do i need to repeat step 1,2 and 3? where would i run 1 and 2 - in anaconda prompt?

Comment: I tried `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 anaconda` in anaconda promopt and got the message `CondaValueError: prefix already exists: C:\Users\nikh\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow`. I went on to type `activate tensorflow` then `python` then ` import tensorflow as tf`and everything went smoothly in anaconda prompt. But I still cannot run tensorflow in spyder

Comment: you need to remove the previous conda environment before you create with the same name. you got the error because you already have an environment named tensorflow. you can remove an environment by conda remove --all tensorflow, if you don't want to remove the environment then create a new one with different name, conda create -n tensorflowspyder python=3.5 anaconda.

Comment: i was able to run tensorflow from spyder after following steps 1 to 5. I installed tensorflow using the command `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensor‌​flow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35‌​m-win_amd64.whl`. Please add your comments to the answer so that I can reward you  the bounty. Would it be possible to answer below questions? 1) what is the difference between the create statment that you have given and one that i used. why does your statement work 2)what is difference between your pip install command and the one that i have used

Comment: 3) to use tensorflow in spyder do i have to always use shortcut that says `spyder (tensorflowspyder)` 4) how should i close python/spyder? Should i log out after deactivating `tensorflowspyder ` from the anaconda prompt?

Comment: 1) The difference is anaconda at the end which installs anaconda as well in addition to python in the virtual environment.
2) There is no difference, you can use either of those if you use pip install tensorflow it installs the latest version but if you use your command it will install specific version.
3) You will need to activate the environment. You can avoid this by installing it directly in command prompt without creating virtual environment but I wouldn't recommend that.
4) Just close it as a regular program

Answer (score 0):

You should active your virtual environment from the command prompt. Once activated, you should run the command `spyder`which will open up the spyder gui from your virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your tensorflow is installed in conda environment. So firsly open the conda prompt as an administrator, then activate tensorflow environment by typing 'activate tensorflow' and then open your spyder gui by typing spyder. It will mostly solve problem.